# xsl:value-of and xsl:for-each ignored in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I try to select attributes from an API XML-response file using XSLT.
This is the request that returns the XML-file: [http://zoekdienst.overheid.nl/sru/Search?version=1.2&operation=searchRetrieve&x-connection=oep&startRecord=1&maximumRecords=10&query=(keyword=verkeersbesluit) and (creator=groningen) and (organisationType=Provincie)](http://zoekdienst.overheid.nl/sru/Search?version=1.2&operation=searchRetrieve&x-connection=oep&startRecord=1&maximumRecords=10&query=(keyword=verkeersbesluit)%20and%20(creator=groningen)%20and%20(organisationType=Provincie))

I created the following XSL-file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:overheid="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/owms/terms/" xmlns:overheidop="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/product/terms/" xmlns:overheidvb="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/vb/terms">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <verkeersbesluiten>
            <test>Hello world!</test>
            <numberOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="searchRetrieveResponse/numberOfRecords"/></numberOfRecords>
            <xsl:for-each select="searchRetrieveResponse/records/record/recordData/gzd/originalData/overheidop:meta/overheidop:owmskern">
                <besluit>
                    <test2>Hello world again!</test2>
                    <titel><xsl:value-of select="dcterms:title"/></titel>
                    <locatie><xsl:value-of select="dcterms:spatial"/></locatie>
                </besluit>    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </verkeersbesluiten>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The resulting file after transformation:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<verkeersbesluiten xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:overheid="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/owms/terms/" xmlns:overheidop="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/product/terms/" xmlns:overheidvb="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/vb/terms">
    <test>Hello world!</test>
    <numberOfRecords/>
</verkeersbesluiten>
```

This is not the result I'd like to have. That would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<verkeersbesluiten xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:overheid="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/owms/terms/" xmlns:overheidop="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/product/terms/" xmlns:overheidvb="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/vb/terms">
    <test>Hello world!</test>
    <numberOfRecords>41</numberOfRecords>
    <besluit>
        <test2>Hello World again!</test2>
        <titel>Provincie Groningen: verkeersbesluit nieuwe situatie parallelweg langs N964 tussen Winschoten en Scheemda.</titel>
        <locatie>264455 576268$%$Oldambt</locatie>
    </besluit>
    <besluit>
        <test2>Hello World again!</test2>
        <titel>Provincie Groningen: verkeersbesluit nieuwe situatie N366, Westerstraat en A.G. Wildervanckweg in Ter Apel</titel>
        <locatie>266425 544276$%$Vlagtwedde<</locatie>
    </besluit>
    ...
</verkeersbesluiten>
```

Could somebody please point out to me what I am doing wrong?

Willy

==========================================================================

As @halfbit suggested, I've added namespaces srw and sru to my XSL-file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:srw="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/" xmlns:sru="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/sru/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:overheid="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/owms/terms/" xmlns:overheidop="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/product/terms/" xmlns:overheidvb="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/vb/terms">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <verkeersbesluiten>
            <test>Hello world!</test>
            <numberOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="srw:searchRetrieveResponse/srw:numberOfRecords"/></numberOfRecords>
            <xsl:for-each select="srw:searchRetrieveResponse/srw:records/srw:record/sru:gzd">
                <besluit>
                    <test2>Hello world again!</test2>
                </besluit>    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </verkeersbesluiten>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<verkeersbesluiten xmlns:srw="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/" xmlns:sru="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/sru/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:overheid="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/owms/terms/" xmlns:overheidop="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/product/terms/" xmlns:overheidvb="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/vb/terms">
  <test>Hello world!</test>
  <numberOfRecords>41</numberOfRecords>
  <besluit>
    <test2>Hello world again!</test2>
  </besluit>
  <besluit>
    <test2>Hello world again!</test2>
  </besluit>
  ...
</besluiten>
```

This looks good. But when I extend the xsl:for-each clause something goes wrong:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl" xmlns:srw="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/" xmlns:sru="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/sru/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:overheid="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/owms/terms/" xmlns:overheidop="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/product/terms/" xmlns:overheidvb="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/vb/terms">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <verkeersbesluiten>
            <test>Hello world!</test>
            <numberOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="srw:searchRetrieveResponse/srw:numberOfRecords"/></numberOfRecords>
            <xsl:for-each select="srw:searchRetrieveResponse/srw:records/srw:record/sru:gzd">
                <besluit>
                    <test2>Hello world again!</test2>
                </besluit>    
            </xsl:for-each>
        </verkeersbesluiten>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This results into:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<verkeersbesluiten xmlns:srw="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/" xmlns:sru="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/sru/" xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:overheid="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/owms/terms/" xmlns:overheidop="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/product/terms/" xmlns:overheidvb="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/vb/terms">
  <test>Hello world!</test>
  <numberOfRecords>41</numberOfRecords>
</verkeersbesluiten>
```

I can't get my head around this. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I've checked this xml input file and found a warning. *"The schema referenced from this location in your document contains errors."* that is `xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/ srw-types.xsd"` and `xsi:schemaLocation="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/sru gzd.xsd"`

Comment: The XML input uses `http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/` as default namespace, whereas the paths in your `select` attributes refer to the empty namespace (`searchRetrieveResponse` etc). You might want to declare the namespace (`xmlns:srw="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/"`) and qualify the elements in the path (`srw:searchRetrieveResponse` etc.) in your XSL file.

Comment: I've added namespaces as @halfbit suggested and changed my original post to reflect these changes. Results improved but I'm still not getting what I expected. Maybe you have another suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:srw="http://www.loc.gov/zing/srw/" 
    xmlns:sru="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/sru" 
    xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" 
    xmlns:overheid="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/owms/terms/" 
    xmlns:overheidop="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/product/terms/"
    xmlns:overheidvb="http://standaarden.overheid.nl/vb/terms">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <verkeersbesluiten>
      <test>Hello world!</test>
      <numberOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="srw:searchRetrieveResponse/srw:numberOfRecords"/></numberOfRecords>
      <xsl:for-each select="srw:searchRetrieveResponse/srw:records/srw:record/srw:recordData/sru:gzd/sru:originalData/overheidop:meta/overheidop:owmskern">
        <besluit>
          <test2>Hello world again!</test2>
          <titel><xsl:value-of select="dcterms:title"/></titel>
          <locatie><xsl:value-of select="dcterms:spatial"/></locatie>
        </besluit>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </verkeersbesluiten>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It differs from your latest XSL in

- the `sru` namespace (it does not have a trailing slash - every character counts)
- the missing `srw:recordData` before the `sru:gzd` in the path.

BTW: If the structure of the XML input permits (only one `owmskern` per `record` expected) you can shorten the `for-each` to

```
<xsl:for-each select="srw:searchRetrieveResponse//overheidop:owmskern">
```

This might be slightly slower but is more readable and - as you experienced - less errorprone to write/maintain.

---

Off the record: In XSLT, some would prefer not to use `for-each` for traversing the input XML because this is what the XSLT processor is doing anyway, and instead write multiple much simpler, more focussed templates, like so:

```
  <!-- only traverse, do not copy anything by default -->
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="srw:searchRetrieveResponse">
    <verkeersbesluiten>
      <test>Hello world!</test>
      <numberOfRecords><xsl:value-of select="srw:numberOfRecords"/></numberOfRecords>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </verkeersbesluiten>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="overheidop:owmskern">
    <besluit>
      <test2>Hello world again!</test2>
      <titel><xsl:value-of select="dcterms:title"/></titel>
      <locatie><xsl:value-of select="dcterms:spatial"/></locatie>
    </besluit>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you very much!